# Facebook login setup for Cognito hosted UI on localhost

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook-login, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use the AWS Cognito hosted UI to allow users to sign in to a userpool using Facebook. I would like to be able to authenticate in my local dev environment. My problem is that I can't seem to figure out the correct URLs to specify to make things work on `localhost:3000`.

I've tried a lot of combinations but I seem to keep getting a "Can't Load UL" error:
[image: Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.]

On the frontend I am using `aws-amplify-react`'s `withOAuth` function to utilize a function that loads the hosted UI:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import { withOAuth } from 'aws-amplify-react';

const oauth = {
    domain: 'my-app-client-domain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com',
    scope: [
        'phone', 'email', 'profile', 'openid', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'
    ],
    redirectSignIn: 'https://localhost:3000/authenticated',
    redirectSignOut: 'https://localhost:3000/logout',
    responseType: 'code'
}
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        oauth: oauth
    }
});

class LoginButton extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<LoginButtonContainer>
            <LoginButton onPress={this.props.OAuthSignIn}>Log in</LoginButton>
        </LoginButtonContainer>);
    }
}
export default withOAuth(LoginButton);
```

My facebook app setup looks like this under "Settings -> Basic":

**App Domains:** `my-app-client-domain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com`

**Website URL:** `https://my-app-client-domain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse`

[image: my-app-client-domain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com]
[image: https://my-app-client-domain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse]

Under "Products -> Facebook Login -> Settings":

Valid OAuth Redirect URIs: `https://localhost:3000/authenticated`
[image: https://localhost:3000/authenticated]

My User Pool settings in AWS console are:

Under "App Integration -> App client settings":
[image: App Client Settings]

Obviously I also have the App integration Domain name setup as "my-app-client-domain", and I have my facebook app setup under "Federation -> Identity providers"

So, to summarize, I currently have the following URL settings:

- Frontend app

  - **domain**: my-app-client-domain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com
  - **redirectSignIn**: https://localhost:3000/authenticated
  - **redirectSignOut**: https://localhost:3000/logout
- Facebook settings

  - **App Domains:** my-app-client-domain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com
  - **Website URL:** https://my-app-client-domain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse
  - **Valid OAuth Redirect URIs**: https://localhost:3000/authenticated
- AWS User Pool settings:

  - **Callback URL(s):** https://my-app-client-domain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse, https://localhost:3000/authenticated
  - **Sign out URL(s):** https://my-app-client-domain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse, https://localhost:3000/logout
  - **Domain prefix:** my-app-client-domain

Do any of my settings look wrong, or is there possibly something unrelated to the actual URLs I may have setup incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out, unsurprisingly, my problem was completely unrelated. I had set the wrong Facebook App ID in AWS for my identity provider, so if you're having this problem, its worth double checking.

That being said, the lack of documentation on setting up your Facebook app to work with Cognito is what sent me down this rabbit hole. Plus I did need to update my URL settings as well, so here are the settings that ended up working for me:

- Frontend app

  - **domain**: my-app-client-domain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com
  - **redirectSignIn**: https://localhost:3000/authenticated
  - **redirectSignOut**: https://localhost:3000/logout
- Facebook settings

  - **App Domains:** localhost
  - **Website URL:** https://localhost:3000/
  - **Valid OAuth Redirect URIs**: https://my-app-client-domain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse
- AWS User Pool settings:

  - **Callback URL(s):** https://localhost:3000/authenticated
  - **Sign out URL(s):** https://localhost:3000/logout
  - **Domain prefix:** my-app-client-domain

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security/#surfacearea "On October 6, 2018, all apps will be required to use HTTPS."